# Responsive size of element in column layout in angularmaterial

Tags: css, angularjs, responsive-design, size, angular-material

I would like to know how to set the width of an element in a column layout in angular material.

Here is a simple code :

```
<div class="inactive-background" flex layout="column" layout-align="start center">
  <md-whiteframe class="md-whiteframe-z2 white-frame" layout-margin>
    <md-content layout-align="center center" layout="row">
      <span class="chrono">00:00:00</span>
    </md-content>
  </md-whiteframe>
</div>
```

With this code, the span is centered but very small :

[image]

in order to resize the whiteframe, I can simply change the width property.

```
<div class="inactive-background" flex layout="column" layout-align="start center">
  <md-whiteframe class="md-whiteframe-z2 white-frame" layout-margin style="width: 600px">
    <md-content layout-align="center center" layout="row">
      <span class="chrono">00:00:00</span>
    </md-content>
  </md-whiteframe>
</div>
```

The result is good, but the problem is that the whiteframe becomes no responsive. If I reduce the size of the browser, the whiteframe still takes 600px width.

The question is : How to do that in the responsive way ?

Thanks you
[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wKeVWe?editors=110)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found (but not sure it is the best solution). Tell me if not

The trick is to wrap the whiteframe into an other div (layout=row) and use flex to set the size :

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NGgQjX?editors=110

```
<div class="inactive-background" flex layout="column">
  <div flex layout="row" layout-align="center start">
    <md-whiteframe class="md-whiteframe-z2 white-frame" layout-margin flex="70">
      <md-content layout-align="center center" layout="row">
        <span class="chrono">00:00:00</span>
      </md-content>
    </md-whiteframe>
  </div>
</div>
```